# SQL Server 2019 Version 15.0.4261.1 Standard TDE

Tags: sql-server-2019, transparent-data-encryption

This is my first post.  I did a search and didn't see anyone else having this problem.

My understanding has been that TDE is available in the Standard version of SQL Server 2019.  Whenever I attempt to run the query

```sql
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128
    ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE TDECertificate;
GO
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 33117, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance. 
See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.
```

I do not know what needs to be done to have TDE available outside of creating the Master key and cert.  Backing them up.

I also tried creating a brand new database just to test it and got the same results.  Am I overlooking something very basic?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: @Peter Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18) (KB5017593) - 15.0.4261.1 (X64)   Sep 12 2022 15:07:06   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Can it be that you are running the script on the wrong database? What if you add USE [DatabaseName] 
GO
<script>

Comment: I attempted this again yesterday and it is working now.

Comment: Perhaps wrong database or server connected. Good it works for you now!

Comment: Çalışan yöntemi yazabilir misiniz?
Can you write the method that works?